# Drawing a semi-transparent rectangle in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I was searching for the answer for so long and also tried to solve it by myself but I couldn't and I think this is the best place to ask. So I am trying to accomplish something simple but I just can't find the way to do it. I think I am missing something on conceptual level. This is how I try to create my semi-transparent rectangle inside my class that is subclassing UIView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //this should be white color with 0.7 opacity right
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.7);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
}
```

Ok, this just makes the color gray. I tried with this also but with the same result: 
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.7);

Another try:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

    self.alpha = 0.7;
}
```

Voila! I solved it. But not exactly. I want to draw a semi-transparent rectangle in the context and not to make the whole view transparent. And then for example add another rectangle which is fully opaque. Would love to hear your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that the reason why you can't see the transparency of your rect is the presence of a background color in your view.

Would you try setting the view background color like this:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

BTW, this statement, as well as any statement setting a property of your custom view (e.g., `self.alpha = 0.7;`) should go into the `init` method.

EDIT:

as pointed out by @borrrden, the real property to set in order to make the trick is possibly `opaque`. This is usually set to `YES` and thus implies the following, according to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/opaque):

> An opaque view is expected to fill its bounds with entirely opaque content—that is, the content should have an alpha value of 1.0. If the view is opaque and either does not fill its bounds or contains wholly or partially transparent content, the results are unpredictable. You should always set the value of this property to NO if the view is fully or partially transparent.

Setting the background color to `clearColor` will likely set the value of this property to `NO` as a collateral effect.

EDIT:

I do not understand why you are overriding `drawRect` in a custom `UIView` to draw a semi-transparent rectangle, maybe because I do not know what you are trying to do. In any case, an alternative approach to this you might want to look into is using nested `UIViews` or nested `CALayers`, where you assign a different `alpha`/`opacity` to any of them.

If you are just interested in rectangles with varying degrees of opacity, this would be as simple as nesting `UIViews` in a parent view and assign the each of them a semi-transparent background color.

Comment: I am betting the reason this works is because the `opaque` property is set to `YES` which causes transparency to be ignored.  Setting the background color to a color with transparency implicitly sets that value to `NO` and allows transparency.

Comment: Wow great, this one solved it, thanks! I don't really get it. I know what 'clearColor' is doing but why should we use it? I mean the documentation says that the default backgroundColor of a UIView is nil which equals transparency. But what I saw from experimenting here is that the default background color is actually black which caused the gray color. Prove me if I am wrong.

Comment: @borrrden: nice catch! This should explain flashadvanced's remark in his comment... I edited my answer to add this insight.

Comment: @flashadvanced Yes, the default value is `nil` but let's analyze it a bit more.  `nil` is the same as saying `0`, so your color will be 0, 0, 0, 0.  That certainly *looks like* transparent, but there is one more factor going on.  That is the `opaque` property.  It is there for speed (It is much easier to calculate an opaque view than a translucent one), and it is usually set to `YES`.  That means that  any alpha in the view itself is ignored and the view is filled with 0, 0, 0 (or black, assuming `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` is set).

Comment: It's been stated in many WWDC videos about performance that setting the alpha of your view, or changing the background color to a color with alpha will set the opaque value to `NO` for you behind the scenes (a point to be aware of if you are running into performance problems) and that is why simply setting the background color that way works.

Comment: @borrrden, now I get it. So the best way to do it from performance point of view is to set 'self.opaque = NO;'?

Comment: @sergio, I actually wanted to show what I am trying to do but couldn't upload a picture due to low reputation. In few words: I am trying to create a preloader-like bar which fills the semi-transparent background with white opaque fill with animating the width. So I think the best approach here would be using nested UIViews as you stated. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can use this ,

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"semiTransparentImage.png"] drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationOut alpha:1.0];
```